# How to calculate the time of closest approach between two orbiting objects

Tags: orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

I have two objects each one moves in elliptic orbit I calculated the distance of closest approach using (the minimum intersection disatnce).Knowing the true anomalies for both objects corresponding to the minimum distance and knowing the orbital period for both objects, I have to find the time of closest approach.
As a beginning, i calculated the required time for each object to be at the point that corresponds to the minimum distance. that is to say, the time T1 and T2(when the two objects at the position q1 and q2 that corresponding to the minimum distance),So my question now I have the time that the first object needs to be in the position q1 and the time that the second object need to be in the position q2 where q1 and q2 are  the true anomalies that corresponding to the minimum distance how can i find the same time where the two objects be at the minimum distance?